# Retrieving UserName using UserID from LookBack

Tags: rally

I am using the LookBack to get historical revision information.
I get the _User value which is a User ID.
How would I go about retrieving the corresponding User Name?

I have played with ModelFactories but no success.

```
 //use lookback api to retrieve user story info
 _createRevisionInfo: function(record, item)
 {
  var userStoryID = item.get('FormattedID');
  var userStoryName = item.get('Name');
  var snapShotFilters = this._getSnapShotFilters(userStoryName, userStoryID);

  //create store
  this.snapshotStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',
  {
    fetch: ['ScheduleState', '_ValidFrom', 'PlanEstimate', '_User'],
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: snapShotFilters,
        hydrate: ['ScheduleState'],
        sortOnFilter: true,
        sortonload: true,
        .
        .
     });
},

_onSnapShotStoreLoad: function()
{       
    if(!this.down('#my-grid2'))
    {
    var columnCfgs = [
        {
            width: 175,
            text: 'Date Changed',
        },
        {
            text: 'State Change',
            width: 335,
        },
        {
            text: 'Author', 
            dataIndex: '_User',
            width: 175,
        }];

        this._createGrid(......);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hydrate users from lookback api.  That would be pretty sweet though!

Your best option for now is to query wsapi for all the users you need to hydrate after your lookback data comes back.  Something like this?

```
_onSnapshotStoreLoad: function(store) {
    var userOids = _.uniq(_.map(store.getRange(), function(record) { return record.get('_User'); }));

    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'User',
        filters: [{ property: 'ObjectID', operator: 'in', value: userOids.join(',')}]
    });
}
```

And then when that store loads you can munge the data into your lookback data and create your grid just like you were.